# Moving N keys from dict, each one is a list of tuples into an N dimension array or other structure

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary with 10 lists in my example, each list contain a tuple of 2 elements, the first element of the tuple is shared between all the other list, 
I want to create an "array" that will contain the ID that each 1st element from the tuple, and the other 10 lists.
for example:
Tdict, is a dictionary containing 2 lists, each list is a tuple list that has 2 elements (ID, value) . I want to create an array that will have: 
(ID, valueA ,ValueB)